# Is it safe to end process emulator-arm.exe (Android emulator) instead of closing it by the close button

Tags: android, process, android-emulator

I have noticed that closing the Android emulator by close button (the top right button) takes a lot of time.

Ending process emulator-arm.exe (through task manager) closes it instantly.
When I open the Android emulator next time, there seems to be **no data loss.**

So is it safe to end process emulator-arm.exe all time?

Comment: I don't know anything about Android itself, but when you close the application like that, there may be data stored in memory that doesn't get cleaned up.

Comment: You should only need to close the emulator when you're done testing for the day -- there's no need to close it each time you launch your app for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably takes long to close because it's saving a snapshot to speed up next startup.
If you are not using the sanpshots you can run the emulator with `-no-snapstorage` option to disable them.

Comment: The startup does speed up!! Thanks.  I noted that the emulator takes more RAM while closing than while starting.  Loading takes about 200 MB RAM whereas closing takes around 800 MB RAM (the memory i have specified for the emulator to use). At the time of closing my RAM usage is near to 100% and that is why there is slowdown.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any data loss that you care about, the answer is yes you can do that.

It should be noted that I don't do that, I close it normally using the close button or closing the emulator window.